# How to specifiy path when using pdb in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, pdb

I am trying to use pdb in emacs. I need to change path to `PYTHONPATH=lib`. But when I typed

`Run pdb (like this): PYTHONPATH=lib pdb ./pychess`.

Emacs gives me an error saying the file PYTHONPATH=lib isn't found. How do I specify path when running pdb in emacs? In terminal PYTHONPATH=lib pdb ./pychess runs fine, but not in emacs.

---

Oh I got it just type `PYTHONPATH=lib emacs` when launching emacs. Not sure about changing path after launching though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to set the environment variable with in the emacs (say putting in `.emacs` or using <kbd>M-:</kbd>) like this

```
(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "lib")
```

Comment: what do you mean by using M- ? What comes after?

Comment: M-: is (alt/Meta and colon) runs the command eval-expression with which you execute small elisp code, another way is ofcourse using *scratch* buffer