# Using pdb in emacs with a miniconda install

Tags: python, emacs, pdb, pythonpath, miniconda

I am trying to use pdb as a python debugger in emacs

I'm getting the import error issues, as in:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18190/missing-modules-when-debugging-python-code-in-emacs

[How to specifiy path when using pdb in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608661/how-to-specifiy-path-when-using-pdb-in-emacs)

the suggested solution, i.e.

```
(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "lib")
```

in `.emacs` or `emacs.d/init.el`

This seems very unsatisfactory as you are effectively duplicating the `pythonpath` data which will trip you up at some point when you update one but not the other.

How can one get the `pythonpath` as used by `pdb` to be exactly the same as that is used say if I open an `ipython` shell.

In other words I want `pdb` to reflect the path locations that get automatically loaded from my `.bashrc` and `miniconda` installation when I open `ipython`

also, how does `ipython` know which miniconda dirs to pull into the `pythonpath`? which file is that specified in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find out where your miniconda install is, for me it was:

   ~/miniconda2
2. Ensure that your `.bashrc PATH` is picking up the miniconda python install *before* any of the default linux installations, i.e. its looking in `~/miniconda2/bin` prior to `/usr/bin/`
3. `Dired` into `~/miniconda2/lib/python2.7`
4. `'S'` to create a soft symlink to `pdb.py`, place the link in `~/miniconda2/bin` and call it `pdb2.7`
5. `Dired` into `~/miniconda2/bin`
6. `'S'` to create a soft symlink to `pdb2.7`, place link in same dir and call it `pdb`
7. Now when you run `M-x pdb` to invoke the python debugger it should pick up the correct version and not complain of any missing modules

Prior to this it was picking up `pdb` from `/usr/bin`, hence all the module import failures. These steps just copy the set of symlinks found in that dir but using the miniconda equivalent files and dirs